# Remote access server that's running through VPN

Tags: server, ssh, vpn

I've have a server running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS that I access through SSH and that is working fine. I'm trying to have the server run through a VPN, so I can change what location it will display when logging into different websites. I've used option B at this site: https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-vpn-setup/ and that is working as well. The problem I have is that when I activate the VPN the IP obviously change, so I can't log in to the server via SSH anymore. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: That would be something for the VPN guys would it not?

Comment: Is the server in your local network?

Comment: Then you simply need to use split tunneling to exclude your local network from the VPN. I don't know about ProtonVPN, but with NordVPN you can use `nordvpn whitelist` command for it. I guess, proton has something similar, ask their support.

Comment: See something like this -> https://www.reddit.com/r/ProtonVPN/comments/6obd7v/private_local_network_traffic_bypass/

Comment: The server is not in my local network. I've submitted a ticket at Proton and asked them, but in the meantime I will check out the link. Thanks for the help so far.

Answer (score 0):

There is a script here to do this:

https://github.com/tool-maker/VPN_just_for_torrents/wiki/Maintaining-SSH-Access-Using-a-VPN-on-a-Remote-Linux-Server

It ensures that when a connection to the real IP interface is made, even if it is not the default gateway interface anymore, response packets for the connection go back on the real interface again. It uses the `ip` and`nft` commands to create some firewall and routing table entries.